# Using Flask Cache with a generator function

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use Flask-Cache to cache a generator function. Flask-Cache requires pickling and since generators can't be pickled, this is a problem. Are there any work-arounds to using a generator with Flask-Cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache the *results* simply call `list` on the generator and store that instead.  If the results are too big to safely stored in memory (even temporarily) then wrap your results in a class instance that can [restore itself when unpickled](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__):

```
# Warning: This is terribly tightly bound together
# There are better ways to do this - this is just by way of example

def some_generator(identifier):
    """This could be anything
        * A database wrapper
        * A permutation generator
        * Something that streams (and transforms) data from disk
        * The possibilities are endless"""
    if identifier == "result_set_1":
        results = [(x, y) for x in range(10) for y in range(x)]
    elif identifier == "result_set_2":
        results = [(x, 0) for x in range(20)]
    else:
        results = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

    for row in results:
        yield row


class GeneratorWrapper(object):
    """
    Use::

        @cache
        some_function(identifier):
            return GeneratorWrapper(identifier)
    """

    def __init__(self, identifier=None):
        self.identifier = identifier
        if identifier is not None:
            self.data = some_generator(identifier)

    def __getstate__(self):
        """When pickled return the key to rebuilding the generator"""
        return self.identifier

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        """When unpickled, restore the generator using the pickled key"""
        self.identifier = state
        if state is not None:
            self.data = some_generator(state)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.data
```